# npm start: "ReferenceError: angular is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I am following the tutorial at https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/ and I get the titular error when I run 'npm start', 'node bin/www', or 'node angApp.js'

I ran the following commands (in order):

```
npm install -g express-generator
express --ejs test
cd test
npm install
npm install --save mongoose
```

It is throwing the error at the first line of my main file "angApp.js":

```
var app = angular.module('entry', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('main', [
'$scope', 
function($scope) {
    // rider = {name, pickup time, pickup location, drop off location, boolean can ride}
    $scope.riders = [];

    $scope.addRider = function() {
        // make sure to check to see if user submitted nothing
        if(!$scope.inName || $scope.inName == '') {return;}
        if(!$scope.pickTime || $scope.pickTime == '') {return;}
        if(!$scope.locPick || $scope.locPick == '') {return;}
        if(!$scope.dropLoc || $scope.dropLoc == '') {return;}

        $scope.riders.push( {name: $scope.inName, time: $scope.pickTime, 
            pick: $scope.locPick, drop: $scope.dropLoc, canRide: true} );
    };
}]);
```

My index.html, which is now index.ejs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dispatching</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/angApp.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="entry" ng-controller="main">

        <div ng-repeat="rider in riders">
            <p>Name: {{rider.name}}</p>
            <p>Pickup time: {{rider.time}}</p>
            <p>Pickup location: {{rider.pick}}</p>
            <p>Drop-off location: {{rider.drop}}</p>
        </div>

        <form ng-submit="addRider()">
            <p>Rider name: <input type="text" ng-model="inName"></input> </p>       
            <p>Pickup time: <input type="text" ng-model="pickTime"></input> </p>
            <p>Pickup location: <input type="text" ng-model="locPick"></input> </p>
            <p>Drop-off location: <input type="text" ng-model="dropLoc"></input> </p>
            <p> <button type="submit">Submit rider</button> </p>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I updated 'bin/www' as such:

```
var app = require('../public/javascripts/angApp');
```

Root of my project structure:

bin/ -- only contains www

node_modules/ -- contains a bunch of stuff

package.json

public/ -- contains directories 'images', 'javascripts', 'stylesheets', all of which are empty except javascripts which contains my 'angApp.js'

routes/ -- contains 'index.js' and 'users.js'

views/ -- contains 'error.ejs' and my 'index.ejs'

I have seen this question asked various times here, but most solutions brought up bower, but I have never used it and I don't even know if I have it.

Comment: Is your connection to google api service accessible? Looks like you haven't loaded angular.js

Comment: Um, I'm not sure? My first 'script src' isn't loading angular? Should I use the uncompressed version from the Google API? Or should I just download/install Angular with npm?

Comment: I was going edit this into my last comment, but it won't let me edit for some reason...so for some more clarity: everything works fine when I open my local index.html file in my browser. Angular would work fine, this is the first time I'm getting this error.